# Finding key in array-valued dictionary by giving an element of array. (CSP)

Tags: python, dictionary, constraint-satisfaction

I am trying to solve a constraint satisfaction problem with python. There are 4 people going to a party at 4 different times.

```
timeDomain = {"4:30" : ["brian", "amber", "chris", "diane"],
              "4:35" : ["brian", "amber", "chris", "diane"],
              "4:40" : ["brian", "amber", "chris", "diane"],
              "4:45" : ["brian", "amber", "chris", "diane"]}
```

The constraint is "amber comes 5 mins before brian". So, how do I compare brian's and amber's times  with this dictionary? I want to write the constraint as a boolean variable named c:

c = ambers time == brians time - 5

(with converting the string values of the minutes to int etc..)

I tried

```
list(timeDomain.keys())[list(timeDomain.values()).index(["brian", "amber", "chris", "diane"])[1]]
```

to find amber's key but it is not working because all the values are the same, I guess.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your dictionary is basically stating what times each person could come. You'll need to introduce variables for amber's time, brian's time etc.. These will be restricted to a particular domain each (one of the four times given in the dictionary, sort of like transposing the dictionary to get 4 times for each person instead of 4 people for each time) and you should be able to state the time difference constraint directly.